# Sending more than 5,000 emails to customers

Tags: email, limits

I have tried everything with regards to sending more than 5,000 to our customers each day. I have tried Apex, workflow/email alerts and cannot do this. In fact, there is NO way of doing this. Simply, we have 400,000 customers and on average need to send 10,000 invoices and appointments out each day. They are not manually sent by clicking a button on the account/contact page. They are sent hourly each day. What do i need to do to send more than 10,000 emails per day to person accounts? What do large companies use?  thanks

Comment: SF is a CRM/platform not a mass email sending tool,, 

we use Marketing Cloud, MailChimp and other app exchange packages when sending such high number of emails

Comment: thanks but these are operational emails to current users. We don't need to use marketing emails. (or we shouldn't have to). Will take a look at them though

Comment: Marketing Cloud is the name of the tool. You can use it for everything related to emails texts push notifications....

Comment: ok thank you for replying

Comment: if your [org was created before Spring 19](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.allocations_email_general.htm&type=5), WF alerts should get you past the 5,000 limit

Comment: Yes, we have had SF since 2018. Which process within SF will allow more than 5,000? I know its not via Apex. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should review the [Increase the Daily Single Email Message limit for your organization](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334435&type=1&mode=1) knowledge article. However, note that Salesforce says:

> Salesforce Support uses extreme scrutiny when reviewing these requests and we rarely approve indefinite increases

You should also note that Salesforce does not count emails sent to Users against this limit, though it does count Contacts and Person Accounts.

Comment: Thanks. we have had limits increased but this is only temporary.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce has always maintained the stance that they are not an "email provider," and not intended to be used for large, persistent mailings. Typical large organizations will use an alternative mail provider, such as MailChimp or ExactTarget (now, Email Studio) for marketing emails, SendGrid or Apsona, or even use their own email servers to send as many emails as necessary.

*Note: A mention for any product or service should not be construed as a promotion for or condoning the use of a particular product or server. Always do your own product and service research before making a purchasing decision.*

Comment: thanks for the reply. Didn't realise the stance you mention.